# Admobs integration is always showing "No ad config found"

Tags: android, admob, firebase-admob

I have implements google admobs in my app and trying to test it.
These are the steps I have followed : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

This is my manifest :

```
<application
.
.
.>
.
.
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-**********~**********"/>
<application/>
```

This is my dependency added to the gradle :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
```

Added this line to my application file :

```
MobileAds.initialize(this);
```

This is my layout file with the admob view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_f2"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/workout_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_profile_stats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/stats_sharable_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="25dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="13dp">

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_profile_stats"
                                android:layout_width="75dp"
                                android:layout_height="75dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/placeholder_profile"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                android:transitionName="profile" />

                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_profile_stats_dup"
                                android:layout_width="75dp"
                                android:layout_height="75dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/placeholder_profile"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                android:transitionName="profile" />
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_width="96dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/max_streak_bg"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_level_num"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="11sp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
                                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
                                tools:text="LEVEL  7 " />
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBKTextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_a3"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                tools:text="Ankit Maheshwari"
                                android:letterSpacing="0.01" />

                            <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_a5"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                tools:text="EDUCATION MASTER"
                                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                                />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/user_bio_tv"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:maxLength="140"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="@string/def_about_me"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_64"
                                android:textSize="11sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                        <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_impact"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="\u20B9 657"
                            android:textColor="@color/clr_6e"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/total_workouts_tv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                                android:gravity="bottom"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_57"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                tools:text="1563" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                                android:gravity="top"
                                android:text="@string/profile_workouts"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_5e"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/non_impact_distance_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/total_distance_tv"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                                    android:gravity="bottom"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black_57"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    tools:text="1563" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/total_distance_unit_tv"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                                    android:gravity="bottom"
                                    android:text="km"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black_37"
                                    android:textSize="11.4sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/distance_label_tv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                                android:gravity="top"
                                android:text="@string/profile_distance"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_5e"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:background="@color/grey_f2" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/streak_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/shoe_streak_icon" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_streak"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                                    android:gravity="top"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black_57"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    tools:text="63" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                                    android:gravity="top"
                                    android:text="@string/profile_streak"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black_5e"
                                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/shoe_max_streak_icon" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_max_streak"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                                    android:gravity="top"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black_57"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    tools:text="63" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                                    android:gravity="top"
                                    android:text="@string/profile_max_streak"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black_5e"
                                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/meals_shared_linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@color/clr_328f6c"
                    android:paddingLeft="27dp"
                    android:paddingRight="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_meal_count"
                        android:text="0 "
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"

                        />
                    <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
                        android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=">"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/adView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        ads:adSize="BANNER"
                        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8172285899785286/**********">
                    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/achievements_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="45dp">

                        <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
                            style="@style/profile_stats_header"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/profile_stats_achievements" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my fragment code where I use the admob :

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .build();
        Timber.d("TEST123 : "+adRequest.isTestDevice(getContext()));
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                Timber.d("TEST123 : AdClosed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                Timber.d("TEST123 : onAdFailedToLoad");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                Timber.d("TEST123 : onAdFailedToLoad : "+loadAdError.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                super.onAdLeftApplication();
                Timber.d("TEST123 : onAdLeftApplication");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                super.onAdOpened();
                Timber.d("TEST123 : onAdOpened");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                Timber.d("TEST123 : onAdLoaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                super.onAdClicked();
                Timber.d("TEST123 : onAdClicked");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdImpression() {
                super.onAdImpression();
                Timber.d("TEST123 : onAdImpression");
            }
        });
```

And this is always displaying this :

```
onAdFailedToLoad : {
      "Code": 3,
      "Message": "No ad config.",
      "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
      "Cause": "null",
      "Response Info": {
        "Response ID": "null",
        "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
        "Adapter Responses": []
      }
    }
```

Comment: did you manage to fix it? I have the same problem.

Comment: @EKRLAZ no still facing the issue. Could you get a solution?

Comment: Hi, @ParthAnjaria do you solved this issue? If yes, please share with us. For a month I am not able to get answers anywhere.

Comment: this error coming for me all of sudden today with test ads, till yesterday it was working fine

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your code is ok, then nothing to worry about during debugging. and it's expected to get normal ads in production.

one more step you an do:
in logcat search for similar line like this :

```
I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("XXXXXXXXXX")) to get test ads on this device.
```

if you found it then, before admob initialization code be like this:

```
RequestConfiguration configuration = new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("XXXXXXXXXX")).build();
```

MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);

don't forget to replace XXXXXXXXXX with your device ID
after that you should find something like this in logcat:

```
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
```

complete guide [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads).

Edited:

As asked , how to be sure before going to production even if you couldn't see the test ads?

The trick in package name!!! how???

Workaround 1:

in gradle file in app level , change your package name to `com.google.android.gms.example.interstitialexample` then test your code, get ads. be sure that testing is fine. change package name again to your package , then roll out to production.

workaround 2:

load [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/admob/InterstitialExample) project. you should get ads. then in this project change the package name to your real package name. you should not get ads. then the code is fine and you can go for production safely.

Final solution:

a ticket must be opened to Admob teams to find out where is the problem and solve it.

Comment: Surely i'll try this. But before publishing to production we need to be sure that a ad is shown, else we cannot such a build to the customer's right?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria, I added 2 work around , please try them

Answer (score 1):

1 - Be sure your manifest is OK. The **meta-data tag** should be inside **application tag** (like an Activity).

2 - This is working for me with interstitial ads:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-********************");
    AdRequest ad = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(ad);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
        }
    });
```

The declaration of mInterstitialAd on the Activity/Fragment is:

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```